# Key-Value doc as list type in Couchbase

Tags: java, couchbase, key-value, nosql

I want to know if there ability to add into couchbase multiple docs having the same key. so a key could act as key for list of values.

So when I want to retrieve a key's value ill be able to get all values as list/array and somehow order them by insert time, etc..

Any idea if I could achieve that design in couchbase?

- I know that in Redis you can append to the same key multiple values

Example of document:

The key is the username: JohnD
and the value is document with details and last login time like this:

```
{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "status":"success", "lastloginDate":"2013-04-14:22:30:14"}
```

The user is going to login couple of times and I want to record each time he logs in with some extra details.

now in some point I want to retrieve that list sorted by time and get specific item from it.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, if you will try store document with existing value, the previous document will be replaced by a new.
So I recommend you to store list of values as document with one key

Comment: and I will be able to sort them? so for example I can retrieve the last inserted one?

Comment: for example, you can write date time in you document, and then sort documents in the view by date time. If you give me the sample of documents I will explain you better

Comment: Sure. I edited my question with farther explanation and a doc example. thanks.